# Maven XTEXT 2.10 external Lexer

Tags: maven, generator, xtext

First of all : sorry for my poor English...

I have a 2.4 Xtext project with an external lexer like that :

```
// In order to separate lexer and parser (both are managed in the same time by default)
        fragment = org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.ex.rt.AntlrGeneratorFragment {
            antlrParam = "-Xconversiontimeout"
            antlrParam = "30000"
            options = {
                backtrack = true
                backtrackLexer = false
            }
        }

        // Uses ANTLR Tools to compile a custom lexer and will also add a binding in the runtime module to use the Lexer
        fragment = parser.antlr.ex.ExternalAntlrLexerFragment {
            // A grammar file with .g will be expected in this package (should be stored in src folder)
            lexerGrammar = "com.group.xxx.xtext.customlexer.CustomEditorLexer"
            runtime = true
            antlrParam = "-lib"
            // This is the folder where the lexer will be created
            antlrParam = "${runtimeProject}/src-gen/com/group/xxx/xtext/customlexer"
        }
```

Now i try to migrate this project to a maven xtext 2.10 but i don't know how do that with the new xtext generator. (The project is working without problem but not with my external lexar).

I try to do something like this :

```
language = StandardLanguage {
        name = "com.group.xxx.xtext.Editor"
        fileExtensions = "xxx"

        serializer = {
            generateStub = false
        }

        parserGenerator = {

            combinedGrammar = false
            antlrParam = "com.group.xxx.xtext/src/com/group/xxx/xtext/customlexer"
            options = {
                backtrack = true
                backtrackLexer = false
            }
```

The lexer and parser are divided into the gen folder but xtext continue to use the generated lexer instead of mine.

Can you advise me on this plz ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FragementAdapter to include `IGeneratorFragment`s like `ExternalAntlrParserFragment`:

```
parserGenerator = {
    antlrParam = "-Xconversiontimeout"
    antlrParam = "30000"
    options = {
        backtrack = true
        backtrackLexer = false
    }
}
fragment = org.eclipse.xtext.generator.adapter.FragmentAdapter {
    fragment = org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.ex.ExternalAntlrLexerFragment {
    // A grammar file with .g will be expected in this package (should be stored in src folder)
        lexerGrammar = "com.group.xxx.xtext.customlexer.CustomEditorLexer"
        runtime = true
        antlrParam = "-lib"// This is the folder where the lexer will be created
        antlrParam = "${rootPath}/${basename}/src-gen/com/group/xxx/xtext/customlexer"
    }
}
```